# bb10 webworks : make a phone call

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

From a **webworks** (HTML5) app, using the **BB10** platform, I would like a to **call a phone number**.

Googling yielded these:

- https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/blackberry.phone.Phone.Call.html
- https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/blackberry.invoke.PhoneArguments.html

They weren't very helpful, as they are essentially blank. (they appear to be stub articles).

How would one do this?

Thanks!

---

## EDIT

I found this other question on SO, regarding opening a browser:
[WebWorks: Open Web Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003341/webworks-open-web-browser)

... and in a similar vein, the documentation also appears to be a stub article:

- https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.invoke.browserarguments.html

If this method of opening a browser does indeed work:

```
var args = new blackberry.invoke.BrowserArguments('http://www.blackberry.com');
blackberry.invoke.invoke(blackberry.invoke.APP_BROWSER, args);
```

... then calling PhoneArguments in the same pattern should be worth a shot:

```
var args = new blackberry.invoke.PhoneArguments (ARG_1, ARG_2, ...);
blackberry.invoke.invoke(blackberry.invoke.APP_XYZ, args);
```

However, I cannot guess what `ARG_*` and `APP_XYZ` should be - any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

The API you found is a WebWorks API, but designed for the older BlackBerry OS (BlackBerry 5, 6 and 7).  It is based on the Java platform and unfortunately not compatible with BlackBerry 10 yet.  A "phone" API has not yet been ported over to BlackBerry 10 (too early for that) however the "tel" scheme is supported.  When the user clicks those types of hyperlinks, they are prompted to make a call.  So you could effectively create a button like this:

```
<a href="tel:555-555-5555">
   <div class="button">This is a button</div>
</a>
```

Here is a live example you can test:

http://blackberry.github.com/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/browser/schemes.html

**EDIT:**

Happy to correct myself, discovered this can also be achieved on BlackBerry 10 through the new invocation framework:

```
blackberry.invoke.invoke({
   uri: "tel:5555555555"
}, onInvokeSuccess, onInvokeError);
```

More on invoke here:

https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/invoke

Answer (score 1):

Try with HTML:
You can also use `<a href="tel:55519112">call</a>` I think